# use velocity, meteor, and travis ci

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, travis-ci

I made a basic application in Meteor, and used [velocity with mocha](http://velocity.meteor.com/). I tried to find ways to build on travis ci. Travis suggested using the following for a `.travis.yml`

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "0.10"
before_install:
  - "curl -L http://git.io/3l-rRA | /bin/sh"
services:
  - mongodb
env:
  - LAIKA_OPTIONS="-t 5000"
```

Unfortunately, this seems to [be based on the deprecated laika framework](http://arunoda.github.io/laika/).

Is there any way to use the velocity framework on a meteor app and have it build on travis ci?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem while trying to get the cucumber tests up and running on Travis.

Turns out it is as simple as installing Meteor through the recommended way on their official site.
Here is the configuration I use on my [project](https://github.com/TFarla/meteor-leaderboard-bdd):

```
sudo: required
language: node_js
node_js: 
  - "0.12"
install: 
  - "curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh"
  - "meteor update"
script: 
  - "meteor --test --once"
env:
  - "SELENIUM_BROWSER=phantomjs"
```